# perform Math operations +-*/% in Ext.XTemplate on two data fields

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

My Model:

```
Ext.define('paymentModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'totalPayment', 'targetCost','itemCount',
        {
            name: 'totalPayment',
            type: 'number',
        },
        {
            name: 'claimsCount',
            type: 'number'
        },
        {
            name: 'targetCost',
            type: 'number'
        }
    ]
});
```

Template i want to write

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
                       '<TABLE width="100%" cellpadding=4 style="margin-top: 10px">',
                       '<TR><TD>Payment Amount</TD><TD>Average/Claim</TD></TR>',
                       '<TR class="ppm-result-value"><TD>{totalPayment}</TD><TD>                {totalPayment/claimsCount}</TD></TR>',
                       '<TR><TD>SOURCE</TD><TD>SOURCE</TD></TR>',
                       '<TR class="ppm-result-value"><TD>{targetCost}</TD><TD>{targetCost/1000}</TD></TR>',
                       '</TABLE>'
                   );
```

Question :

{targetCost/1000} is calculated (also e.g given in sencha docs).
how can i compute {totalPayment/claimsCount} and {totalPayment%claimsCount} in XTemplate.
I am new to extjs and trying out few things for my project. I have gone throught he sencha documentation , but could not figure out the right way to get this work. 
Seeking help from experienced Ext developers. My apologies if its answered in other threads , i searched and got no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute inline JavaScript code in your template to perform basically any calculation with your values:

```
'<td>{[values.totalPayment / values.claimsCount]}</td>'
```

Refer to the section *"Execute arbitrary inline code with special built-in template variables"* at the documentation of [`Ext.XTemplate`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate).

Also see this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/63g) based on the example in the documentation of [`Ext.view.View`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.View).

Comment: Thank you Matt , this is perfect solution and it worked like charm. Also thanks for quick response !!